# HTML5 Canvas stops redrawing on Firefox Android

Tags: android, html, firefox, canvas

I have an HTML with an animated canvas. On Firefox for Android, when I block the phone or switch apps and then return to Firefox, the canvas stops redrawing. The only way to make the canvas start redrawing itself again is to click anywhere outside the canvas (sometimes this doesn't work) or change its style.

For now, I'm doing a dumb workaround where I add `transform:translateZ(0)` to the canvas and then remove
it in a 1 second interval. That way, I force the browser to redraw the canvas without the user noticing, and it makes it resume updating for some reason.

Tried on Firefox 86.1.1 with Android 11 (This problem doesn't happen on Chrome by the way).

Below is the code. It's taken from Mozilla's Canvas tutorial.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script>
    var sun = new Image();
    var moon = new Image();
    var earth = new Image();
    function init() {
      sun.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1456/Canvas_sun.png';
      moon.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1443/Canvas_moon.png';
      earth.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1429/Canvas_earth.png';
      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    function draw() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300); // clear canvas

      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.4)';
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(150, 150);

      // Earth
      var time = new Date();
      ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 60) * time.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 60000) * time.getMilliseconds());
      ctx.translate(105, 0);
      ctx.fillRect(0, -12, 40, 24); // Shadow
      ctx.drawImage(earth, -12, -12);

      // Moon
      ctx.save();
      ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 6) * time.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 6000) * time.getMilliseconds());
      ctx.translate(0, 28.5);
      ctx.drawImage(moon, -3.5, -3.5);
      ctx.restore();

      ctx.restore();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(150, 150, 105, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); // Earth orbit
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.drawImage(sun, 0, 0, 300, 300);

      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    init();
    </script>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

New workaround. Do the `translateZ(0)` trick when the page is visible again, instead of every second (I tried `cancelAnimationFrame`, but that doesn't work):

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(){
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
        canvas.style.transform = "translateZ(0)";
        setTimeout(function(){canvas.style.transform = "none";}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get a feeling the problem is not in your code or in cavas but in the way that firefox for android handles the app switch ... test other animated canvas see if same happens, here are a couple I have: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_triangles.html, https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/fractal2.html

Comment: @HelderSepulveda
Thanks for the examples. The first one has the same problem, but the second one changing the pixels of an ImageData works. I added the drawing of Mozilla's example on top of "fractal2" and the problem would reappear. It seems the culprit could be "beginPath". If I remove the drawing functions that use it, everything works.

Comment: Interesting ... can you test this other one:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/canvas_board.html
there I'm also using `beginPath` but the "animation" is on the mousemove event, when we place the mouse over the objects the color changes

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Clicking does work. Using requestAnimationFrame, setInterval and setTimeout to work like setInterval doesn't work.